# ¿ Cómo verificar si la computadora cuenta con un programa requerido para la instalación de un software de Java?

Tags: java, windows-forms, java-swing, exe, inno-setup

Tengo un sistema hecho en Java, Ahora estoy haciendo un ejecutable pero el problema es **que el software requiere necesariamente de un programa Java (JDK)**

Entonces como puedo verificar si la computadora cuenta con  dicho programa, si no cuenta que instale o en caso que ya este instalado que verifique la versión si no 
 es la adecuada que actualice.

El programa que estoy usando para hacer el ejecutable **EXE** es **launch4j** y **Inno Setup Compiler**

- tambien encontre **Jar2Exe**

Comment: Inno no tiene una parte donde le podes decir las dependencias?

Comment: Puedes tomar por referencia un archivo del software que quieres comprobar y por me dio de programación comprobar si ese archivo esta ahí.

Answer (score 0):

- Implementa el JRE (y no el JDK) en el instalador (la version que viene en comprimida .tar.gz, pero tu la descomprimes para que Inno Setup tome la carpeta y la comprima el mismo), asi puedes descomprimir (Inno Setup) el JRE en la carpeta del programa:

  ```
  [Files]    
  Source: "C:\PATH_A_TU_CARPETA_DESCOMPRIMIDA_DE_JRE\jre\*"; DestDir: "{app}\jre"; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
  ```
- Configura el path de la carpeta del **JRE** en el **Launch4J** para que lo encuentre y pueda utilizar ese para correr tu programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo esto no necesitas que este instalado Java en el ordenador ni buscar si hay algo faltante, simplemente lo corres desde la carpeta jre del directorio del programa.